# Go Deep understanding of custom error handling in REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, go, go-http

I am coming from the world of Node.js where I learn a lot from building web application using **Express** and there, there is a good way, I think, to handle when dealing with error and in case of unexpected error, there is a awesome way to catch it.

So, I looked for the same thing in Go. I don't know if I have already found it, but what I found come from this link https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/11.1.html and from some articles I read, it seems like many developers are using the same approach.

My concern, and not a real one, is that I don't understand some part of that code below.

```golang
type appHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error

func (fn appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := fn(w, r); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    }
}
```

I know that it's possible to create custom type in go, but seriously I don't understand what this one means or how to understand it in the **http.Serve**

```
type appHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error
```

and one of the thing that I don't catch is

```
func (fn AppHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
```

In most of the code I read, generally, it's a struct or a replaced type (I mean `type Account int`) but here, it's a function.
I would like to understand how is it going to help in handling errors.

Inside the implementation of the `ServeHTTP` up there, we have this line `err := fn(w, r)`.
Please, can you explain it?

From the same article, we have this code

```
func viewRecord(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    key := datastore.NewKey(c, "Record", r.FormValue("id"), 0, nil)
    record := new(Record)
    if err := datastore.Get(c, key, record); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return viewTemplate.Execute(w, record)
}
```

and this line

```
func init() {
    http.Handle("/view", appHandler(viewRecord))
}
```

Please, could you help me to understand this `appHandler(viewRecord)`? What is it exactly? It is an instantiation, is it casting?
What is it supposed to do? I mean, how to understand that line that seems critical?

One last question, please. Is it possible to catch an error that might happen anywhere during the treatment of a request? In Node.js, you can just do something like

```
const app = express()

const errorHandler = (
  err: Error,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (err instanceof CustomError) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).send({ errors: err.serializeErrors() });
  }
  
  res.status(500).send({ 
    errors: [{ message: err.message || 'Something went wrong' }]
  });
}

app.use(errorHandler())
```

Something like that, is it possible in Go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, we can define custom types from any primitive types,
example:

```
type A int
type Person struct{}
```

This is common for functions al well. You can define a Go type with desired function signature like in `appHandler` type in above example. I have added simple example below.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type IntFun func(a,b int) error
func main(){
    var addFunc IntFun
    addFunc = func(a, b int) error {
        if a ==0 || b == 0 {
            return errors.New(`zero valued inputs`)
        }
        fmt.Println(`sum := `, a+b)
        return nil
    }

    addFunc.Add(5, 3) //Output: sum :=  8
    addFunc.Add(0, 0) //Output: zero valued inputs
}

func (fn IntFun) Add(a, b int)  {
    err := fn(a,b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

and also refer [user-defined-function-type-go](https://golangbyexample.com/user-defined-function-type-go/)

In your case,

```
func init() {
    http.Handle("/view", appHandler(viewRecord))
}
```

This is the http endpoint handling part. `"/view"` is the path pattern and other argument is the handler for the request. That parameter should implement [Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) interface in `net/http` Go package. So that's why app handler type have `ServeHttp` function.

`viewRecord` function is also compatible with type `appHandler` function type. it handle the request coming to "/view" endpoint. So it is casted to `appHandler` type and passed to `http.Handle("/view", appHandler(viewRecord))` Handle function.

I think this will explain the scenario. Please comment if anything not clear.

Comment: The name of the language is Go, not golang.

Comment: Sorry @Volker. I have corrected it. Appreciate your comment.